# How to get this type of div container with bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I searched about bootstrap container class and it seems to me that by default it comes with this grid. But its not giving me all three like shown in this picture its showing me only one when I run this code in browser. I added content inside this.

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

[image: Grid am talking about]

Comment: Please clarify the question and [read the bootstrap grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/). The `container` is just a container it doesn't magically contain 3 columns.

Comment: Please read the docs first. Boilerplate: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/bootstrap

Comment: @Zim actually the site where I looked about this, it shown be this.

Comment: @naveen can you guide me how to have like this three?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to do this.

Code

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.data-row {
  height: 150px;
}
.first, .second-1, .second-2 {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.first {
  background-color: #daeeff;
}
.second-1 {
  background-color: #957bbe;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.second-2 {
  background-color: #fae3c4;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col first">
      first
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row data-row">
    <div class="col-10 second-1">
      second
    </div>
    <div class="col second-2">
      menu
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Why there are two div with row class?